# How to select specific elements that dont have a specific class

Tags: css

I have this CSS code that isn't wanting to work for some reason. Everything I read on here indicates that it should.

I am trying to apply a style to all input elements with the types text and password, but not the class input-overrride

```
input[type="text"]:not(.input-override),
input[type="password"]:not(.input-override) {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #fff;
    transition: border 0.3s;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvitica,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:not(.input-override),
input[type="text"]:hover:not(.input-override),
input[type="password"]:focus:not(.input-override),
input[type="password"]:hover:not(.input-override) {
    border-bottom: solid 2px #ff2400;
}
```

If there is a simpler way to do what I am trying to do, please, do let me know.

Comment: we can't read that...

Comment: Works fine... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdPzeM

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was stupid. I changed a letter saved, changed it back, save again and it started working...

Sorry guys...